# In MVC4, how to save data in Controller from postback? (Only those fields in View)

Tags: entity-framework, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a View that edit "Store" table.  This is all fine and good, but the View doesn't display all fields, and when I try to save, it throw error saying the fields that aren't in the View Post can't be blank.  Well, of course, but those fields aren't suppose to be overridden anyway, the View isn't editing them.

Here is my Post Function

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Store storeModel) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            Store storeContext = database.Stores.Find(storeModel.ID);
            database.Entry(storeContext).CurrentValues.SetValues(storeModel);
            database.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Searching online, apparently the problem is that MVC doesn't know which fields you are editing and just treat every field as edited as far as it's concerned, even if the field doesn't exist in the postback.  To "tell" which field you are editing in the View, you have to do this:

```
            //Store contextStore = new Store { ID = postBackStore.ID };
            //database.Stores.Attach(contextStore );
            //contextStore .Name = postBackStore.Name;
            //contextStore .Address = postBackStore.Address;
            //contextStore .City = postBackStore.City;
            //contextStore .Postal = postBackStore.Postal;
            //contextStore .Phone = postBackStore.Phone;
            //contextStore .StoreNumber = postBackStore.StoreNumber;
            //contextStore .IsActive = postBackStore.IsActive;
            //database.Entry(contextStore).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

However, this didn't work for me because MVC complain that it is already tracking the Store object and can't create a new one with the same ID.  Also, I don't like how I have to define all the fields again when I already defined them in the View.

**Is there anyway I can have MVC save change to only the fields in View (as oppose to every field in the model) without having to define explicitly which fields are in the View?**

Comment: Create a separate model for each view.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use viewmodel with just the participating fields ?

Comment: Oh sorry, misunderstood you.  I would like to keep all the fields in the model because I like to use it somewhere else, like in reports.

Comment: I used to feel the same way about the model, and I'm pretty sure that my reasoning was the same.  I changed my mind a long time ago and Ia m glad that I did.  Just as the others have recommended, **Use a separate ViewModel** (or DTO or whatever you would like to call it).